# Can't create new Google Analytics properties

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I can't create any more GA properties...is there a limit to how many I can have?...and is there a limit to views?

Lastly, is there any way to manipulate the properties to have more?

Thanks!
Every time you help me you save a kitten!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have 100 GA accounts per Google login (premium and non-premium), and 50 views for a non-premium account (100 for premium),  and 50 properties per non-premium or premium account.

Sources: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtProfileGuide and https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUserPermissions.

Comment: No, I don't think so. There used to be a way to increase the number of GA accounts that a single login account could have, but I think that 'hack' doesn't exist anymore. You can read more about this hack here: http://gatipoftheday.com/google-analytics-account-limit-raised-from-25-to-100/